# Python Pandas - find row based on two column conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have this table for example:

[image: Example Data]

If **your_pack_size** is the same as **competitor_pack_size**, then **your_measurement** should not be the same as **competitor_measurement**

I would like to find the rows where this condition is broken (if any)

This is what I have tried already:

```
if (df_pr['your_pack_size'].any() == df_pr['competitor_pack_size'].any()):

  print('your_pack_size is the same as competitor_pack_size')

  print(df_pr.loc[df_pr['your_pack_size'].any() == df_pr['competitor_pack_size'].any()]['competitor_product_id'])
```

but I get an error. How can I print out the competitor_product_id where the condition is broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df[(df['your_pack_size'] == df['competitor_pack_size']) & (df['your_measurement'] == df['competitor_measurement'])]
```

i.e. get the rows where the sizes are the same AND the measurements are the same

See conditional selection in pandas, very handy to know https://www.includehelp.com/python/conditional-selection-in-the-dataframe-pandas-dataframe.aspx